# If date = today update row, else, create new row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on a userform to record counts at certain times of the day.

[image]

I automatically add the date and day to the first two fields. There are different fields for one day of the week compared to the others, hence the if statement:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If Format(Date, "ddd") <> "Sat" Then
    DateWkd.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
    DayWkd.Value = Format(Date, "ddd")
Else
    DateSat.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd")
    DaySat.Value = Format(Date, "ddd")
End If
End Sub
```

Data will be submitted at different times of the day.

How do I find if the last row's day value equals today's day to update the row, or create a new row if the date doesn't match?

Comment: if you know which column you want to be in, you can use *cells(rows.count,varDay).end(xlup).row* to find the last row in that respective column.  Where *varDay* is the variable column for finding the last day used.  you can then check that cell to see if same as today, then determine if values go into last row or last row + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will write out a little bit more as comments aren't great for code.

In general, you should appropriately qualify references, so in this case with using your userform, you will need to specify the sheet/etc.

```
Dim lr as Long, varDay as Long
varDay = 1  'assumes using ColumnA, but you could make this a Find() function if necessary
With Sheets("Data")
    lr = .Cells( .Rows.Count, varDay).End(xlUp).Row
    If DateTextBox.Value <> .Cells(lr,varDay).Value Then 'Not sure if you want just Date (todays' date, no time) or the value in your input for the comparison (gave arbitrary name for textbox example)
        'Do your thing
    End if
End With
```

This would be in your command button for entering data, to determine where it would go.  If you need to pull data from the sheet on initialize, you would then set textbox.value = .cell references... note that these two situations are not within the same module.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the explanation. That did it.

Comment: Quick follow-up. If starting a blank sheet with a header row, how to I skip the header row? This wipes out my header row. If I do `lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, varDay).End(xlUp).Row+1` it adds a new row every time I hit submit. Thanks again

Comment: nvm. figured out the offset